# Laravel lumen illuminate/console won't update

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to install Laravel Dusk on my lumen project but I keep getting the following error:

```
Problem 1
    - Installation request for illuminate/queue (installed at v5.4.36) -> satisfiable by illuminate/queue[v5.4.36].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[5.8.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[5.9.x-dev, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.0, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.11, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.12, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.14, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.15, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.17, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.18, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.19, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.2, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.3, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.4, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.8, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Can only install one of: illuminate/console[v5.8.9, 5.4.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: install illuminate/console 5.4.x-dev
    - Installation request for illuminate/console ^5.8 -> satisfiable by illuminate/console[5.8.x-dev, 5.9.x-dev, v5.8.0, v5.8.11, v5.8.12, v5.8.14, v5.8.15, v5.8.17, v5.8.18, v5.8.19, v5.8.2, v5.8.3, v5.8.4, v5.8.8, v5.8.9].
```

I have tried:

```
composer require illuminate/console
composer dump-autoload
composer update
composer install
```

With no luck. In my composer.json there is no illuminate/console so I can't update it in there.

```
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.6.4",
    "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.4.*",
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2",
    "krisanalfa/lumen-dingo-adapter": "^0.0.3",
    "sorskod/larasponse": "*",
    "league/flysystem": " ~1.0",
    "league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "^1.0",
    "maatwebsite/excel": "^2.1",
    "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.0",
    "illuminate/mail": "5.4"
},
"require-dev": {
    "fzaninotto/faker": "~1.4",
    "phpunit/phpunit": "~5.0",
    "mockery/mockery": "~0.9",
    "flipbox/lumen-generator": "^5.4"
},
```

However when I look in the composer.lock that gets created I can see it here:

```
"name": "illuminate/console",
        "version": "v5.4.36",
        "source": {
            "type": "git",
            "url": "https://github.com/illuminate/console.git",
            "reference": "4f0413ffd240d2004c3e9e4cd8f63df249939a15"
        },
```

Any way I can get this pack age to update? I believe `dusk` requires `5.7.*` at minimum.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not able to replicate your issue with the `illuminate/console` package, but I did manage to install the specified packages in a test project on my local machine.

Make sure you have the following in your composer.json file:

```
{
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "prefer-stable": true
}
```

Delete your vendor folder:

```sh
cd ~/path/to/project
rm -rf vendor/
```

Then run `composer update` to ignore and generate a new lock file.

Comment: `"minimum-stability": "dev",` from where in `composer.json`?

Comment: Anywhere in the root object